# Ambiguous procedure error MS Word 2010 VBA

Tags: vba, forms, validation, ms-word

I have several plain text content controls in a Microsoft Word 2010 document. Through VBA code, I am using the Document_ContentControlOnExit event to validate the information upon exiting each text box content control. The code for the first text content control works fine. However, when I use the same code to validate the other text content controls albeit substituting the appropriate function parameters, I get a VBA error of "Ambiguous Name Detected". A sample of my code appears below:

```
private sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal text1 as ContentControl, cancel as Boolean)
    if text1.ShowingPlaceholderText Then 'Field is empty
        msgBox "This field cannot be blank"
        cancel = True
    End if
End sub
```

text1 is the value for the tag property of first text box content control.
What am I doing wrong here? I appreciate any help given!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ambiguous Name Detected usually means there's more than one function with the name. Search for Document_ContentControlOnExit and delete unwanted duplicates.

Using the default name for the content control parameter (or just "cc") instead of "text1" would be best since it's the current control that's referenced in the sub.

Here's a file with your code working
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13440554/share/ContentControlOnExit.docm

Hope this helps